# Pytest cov doesn't recognize option

Tags: python, pytest, coverage.py, pytest-cov

I'm running pytest with pytest-cov with the following command line:

```
python -m pytest Mytools\tests --junitxml test_reports\unittest_result.xml --cov . --cov-branch --cov-report xml:test_reports\unittest_coverage.xml --cov-config=scripts\.coveragerc || exit /b 1
```

however I get this error:

**CoverageWarning: Unrecognized option '[report] exclude_also=' in config file scripts\.coveragerc**

My .coveragerc file looks like this:

```
[report]
exclude_also =
    if __name__ == .__main__.:
```

Any idea on how to fix it?
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of coverage.py: `exclude_also` was introduced in [version 7.2.0](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/7.2.7/changes.html#version-7-2-0-2023-02-22).

Comment: I don't use coverage, I use the latest version of pytest-cov (4.1.0)

Comment: pytest-cov is a wrapper around coverage.py.  You are using coverage.py.  Use `pip list` to see what version you have.